# hermitian operators with the same spectra

Tags: spectra

I want to prove that if two hermitian matrices say $H_1$ and $H_2$ have the same spectra, then one of them is conjugate of the other by some unitary matrix.

$$H_1 = U H_2 U^{\dagger}$$

Any idea?

Comment: Can you add some context? Where is this problem from? What's a Hermitian Matrix?

Comment: Of course $H_1, H_2$ must have the same spectrum **counting multiplicity**.  You are talking about the so-called "spectral theorem" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem